# How to tell if code needs to be run on the UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I'm using a worker thread in my app so it's vital for me to know which code can be run from the worker thread and which code needs to be run on the UI thread.

In the Android documentation, the following hints can be found:

> So, you must not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do
>   all manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread. [...]
>   However, note that you cannot update the UI from any thread other than
>   the UI thread or the "main" thread.

([source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html))

But what "manipulation to your user interface" means in practice is often not as clear as it seems. Of course, it's clear that you cannot hide views, manipulate button texts, add list view entries, etc. from a worker thread.

But what about calling `setRequestedOrientation()` from a worker thread, for example? Is that allowed or does it fall under UI manipulation and thus must be called from the UI thread? Is there any way to tell or should I stay safe and better run the code on the UI thread when in doubt?

Comment: "Is there any way to tell" -- if you call it from a background thread and you crash with an exception indicating that you cannot call that from a background thread, then you need to use the main application thread. In some cases, you might get a Lint warning/error about the problem at compile time.

Comment: `setRequestedOrientation()` works fine from a background thread. So does that mean it is allowed to call it from a background thread or is it just pure luck and next time it can crash?

Comment: AFAIK, the behavior should be consistent. If the framework does not complain about the thread that you use, it is the framework's job to ensure thread safety. But, it is possible that the results will vary by OS version or based on manufacturer tweaks. If you are really risk-averse, do the work on the main application thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should take guidance from the API documentation. For example the [Activity.onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) explicitly states that:

> This method must be called from the main thread of your app.

For the example you gave [Activity.setRequestedOrientation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)) there is no explicit statement that the method should be called on a particular thread. Usually if threading is of concern the documentation will state that.

If you would prefer certainty then you called also call upon [Activity.runOnUiThread()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))